# Как читать память процесса на linux?

Tags: python, linux, память

Необходимо прочитать память процесса. На Windows есть библиотека ctypes, с помощью которой можно использовать [win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712585/readprocessmemory-with-ctypes) и все работает. Но мне необходимо реализовать тоже самое в Linux (а именно Ubuntu, если это имеет значение).

Comment: ctypes везде есть.

Comment: Но я не нашел, как с его помощью читать память в linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека ptrace  -  библиотека системных вызовов Unix-подобных систем. Есть там и доступ к памяти.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html